# Docker how to pull specific Debian version

Tags: docker, dockerfile, debian

I am not sure how to pull a specific Debian version from [this official page](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/) to run/create a container.

How do I pull `stretch-slim` and run locally?

```
docker pull stretch-slim
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for stretch-slim, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: `docker pull debian:stretch-slim`? It actually shows it on the page you linked to, if you go to the tag you want: https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=stretch

Comment: Ah, I did not know that it was available through there. Cool :)